# Доверительные интервалы для параметров регрессионной модели в Python

Tags: python, numpy, статистика, статический-анализ, sklearn

Есть 2 выборки X,Y, необходимо построить модель Y=aX+b+eps. Нужно для параметров a,b найти **доверительные интервалы**.

Я написал поиск интервалов самостоятельно, основываясь на соответствующих формулах из учениках.
(teta- матрица параметров, 252 - объем выборки, предполагается нормальное распределение, то есть 2 параметра, уровень надежности a=0.05)

```
a_left = teta[0]-stats.t.ppf(0.975,250)*math.sqrt(eps2.sum()*C[0,0]/250)
a_right = teta[0]+stats.t.ppf(0.975,250)*math.sqrt(eps2.sum()*C[0,0]/250)
b_left = teta[1]-stats.t.ppf(0.975,250)*math.sqrt(eps2.sum()*C[1,1]/250)
b_right = teta[1]+stats.t.ppf(0.975,250)*math.sqrt(eps2.sum()*C[1,1]/250)
```

Однако мне необходимо(не по своей воле) использовать только штатные возможности библиотек(stats, sklearn, numpy, scipy etc...). **Есть ли в этих библиотеках такая встроенная функция?**

На данный момент удалось только найти параметры в модели

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import metrics

model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
y_pred = model.predict(x)
print("a,b= ",  model.coef_[0], model.intercept_)
```

Comment: Можно посмотреть, например, на `statmodels`: https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/ols.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если к *штатным возможностям* вы относите `scipy` и `numpy`, то доверительные интервалы для линейной регрессии можно найти несколькими способами.

Какой бы способ вы ни выбрали, для вычисления доверительного интервала нужно знать сам параметр (например, `a`) и его среднеквадратичное отклонение (пусть будет `a_err`).

Доверительный интервал с уровнем доверия `alpha` вычисляют по распределению Стьюдента:

```
conf_int = scipy.stats.t.interval(1-alpha, df=n-2, loc=a, scale=a_err)
```

Если нужно найти только полуширину интервала - ту величину, которая ставится после знака ±, то она вычисляется так:

```
plus_minus = abs(sps.t.ppf(alpha/2, n-2))*a_err
```

Теперь как найти параметры и их ошибки.

## Средствами linregress

[`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html#scipy.stats.linregress) - специализированный метод вычисления линейной регрессии.

```
import scipy.stats as sps

n = len(x)
lin_model = sps.linregress(x, y)
a,b = lin_model.slope, lin_model.intercept
# оценка ср.кв. ошибки для a и b
a_err, b_err = lin_model.stderr, lin_model.intercept_stderr
# Доверительный интервал для alpha=5%
a_conf = sps.t.interval(0.95, df = n-2, loc=a, scale=a_err)
b_conf = sps.t.interval(0.95, df = n-2, loc=b, scale=b_err)

print(f"a = {a:0.4f}, α=5% [{a_conf[0]:0.4f} - {a_conf[1]:0.4f}]")
print(f"b = {b:0.4f}, α=5% [{b_conf[0]:0.4f} - {b_conf[1]:0.4f}]")
```

Результат для 100 точек на прямой `y=0.5x+2` со случайной ошибкой `sigma=0.5`:

```
a = 0.5291, α=5% [0.4971 - 0.5610]
b = 1.8568, α=5% [1.6718 - 2.0418]
```

## Универсальный инструмент `curve_fit`

В `scipy` есть универсальный инструмент приближения набора точек заданной моделью [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). Эта функция ищет наилучший набор параметров методом наименьших квадратов для любого вида моделей, не только линейных. Помимо оптимальных значений параметров функция возвращает ковариационную матрицу, диагональные элементы которой дают оценку дисперсии параметров.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps
import scipy.optimize as spo

def linear(x, a,b):
    return a*x+b

((a,b), cov) = spo.curve_fit(linear, xdata=x, ydata=y)
a_err, b_err = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
a_conf = sps.t.interval(0.95, df = n-2, loc=a, scale=a_err)
b_conf = sps.t.interval(0.95, df = n-2, loc=b, scale=b_err)
```

Результат для того же набора данных:

```
a = 0.5291, α=5% [0.4971 - 0.5610]
b = 1.8568, α=5% [1.6718 - 2.0418]
```

Как видно, результат тот же, что для специализированного средства.

## Прямое вычисление

Можно напрямую вычислить параметры линейной регрессии по формулам

```
# Вычисление параметров модели
sum_x = x.sum()
sum_y = y.sum()
sum_xy = (x*y).sum()
sum_x_sq = (x*x).sum()
a = (n*sum_xy - sum_x*sum_y)/(n*sum_x_sq - sum_x*sum_x)
b = (sum_y*sum_x_sq - sum_x*sum_xy)/(n*sum_x_sq - sum_x*sum_x)

# вычисление ошибки параметров
u = y - (a*x+b)
u_avg = np.mean(u)
sigma_square = 1.0/(n-2)*np.sum((u - u_avg)**2)
x_mean = np.mean(x)
dx_square = np.sum((x-x_mean)**2)

a_err = np.sqrt(sigma_square/dx_square)
b_err = np.sqrt(sigma_square*(1.0/n + np.mean(x)**2/dx_square))
```

## Замеры производительности

Линейная регрессия для 100 точек

1. Прямое вычисление:  51.6 µs ± 2.47
2. `linregress` : 207 µs ± 2.67 µs
3. `curve_fit`: 237 µs ± 8.29 µs

Результат линейной регрессии на графике.

[image: линейная регрессия]

## Пример

[Пример загружен в github](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/python/1283898/linear_reg.ipynb) как jupyter notebook.

Comment: Спасибо за очень подробный ответ)

Comment: @Юрий я добавил в начало ответа как в принципе считать доверительные интервалы в python

Comment: Спасибо, и так видно в  a_conf = sps.t.interval(0.95, df = n-2, loc=a, scale=a_err). Не разобрался в терминологии англоязычной, поэтому и был затуп

Answer (score 0):

Странно как-то вы вычисляете доверительный интервал для коэффициентов. Не знаю, на каких учебниках вы основываетесь, но вот посмотрите тут:

http://mcimeer.narod.ru/data/t5/t5_2.html

Она отличается от той, которую вы пытаетесь применить и несколько отличается от той, которую (для коэффициента b) привел уважаемый Pak Uula

Comment: Согласен, в исходном варианте я неверно посчитал дисперсии. Как оказалось, их можно было вообще не считать. `curve_fit` возвращает ковариационную матрицу. Дисперсии параметров модели стоят на диагонали матрицы ))